# web2py Error :- unable to detect browser

Tags: python, web2py

i install a web2py on my machine. i simply click on web2py.exe then it asking for password then it says "unable to detect your browser".

Any help will be appreciable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not an error, it is just a warning message.

This message is being introduced by [this line](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/source/browse/gluon/widget.py#78) which propose is just to open the web browser automatically.

But, even without webbrowser module you should be able to run web2py and ignore the warning message,

If you are unable to run web2py or having any trouble, please open an [issue ticket](http://code.google.com/p/web2py/issues/list) and web2py developers will look in to it.

Answer (score 1):

The message is coming from here:

```
def try_start_browser(url):
""" Try to start the default browser """

try:
    import webbrowser
    webbrowser.open(url)
except:
    print 'warning: unable to detect your browser'
```

You might try the webbrowser.open from a python cli shell to see what the specific exception is. On my (OS X) system:

```
~ $ python
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86882M, Nov 30 2010, 10:35:34) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open('http://stackoverflow.com')
True
```